# Как можно реализовать корзину с помощью сессий во Flask?

Tags: python, flask, python-3.6

Начала изучать питон и фласк, возникли некоторые трудности.
Моя идея такая - при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить в корзину", в обработчик передаются параметры товара, записываются в сессию и на странице корзины выводятся все товары, которые есть в сессии.
В пхп я бы сделала это как-то так:

```
$_SESSION["cart"][] = array("product_name" => "$_POST['product_name']");
```

Но в питоне столкнулась с тем, что не знаю, как передать в параметр сессии список или словарь, и вообще не знаю, что и как туда правильно было бы передать. На данных момент работает добавление только одного товара, он выводится, но при добавлении второго товара все переписывается на новый товар и старый затирается, что логично.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    session['product_name'] = request.form['product_name']
    session['product_image'] = request.form['product_image']
    session['product_description'] = request.form['product_description']

    return render_template('cart.html', session=session)
```

Может я не в ту сторону думаю? Как грамотно это было бы реализовать?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать лист в session и через append добавлять туда товары

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вам уже посоветовал @kot_mapku3 в комментарии...

Нужно в сессии создавать список (в php вы же тоже список создаете):

```
# если корзина ещё не создана
if not session.get('cart'):
   session['cart'] = []

# добавляем инфу о товаре в список
session['cart'] += [{
    'product_name': request.form['product_name'],
    'product_image': request.form['product_image'],
    'product_description': request.form['product_description'],
}]
```